# How to change i18n dynamically with bootstrap selectpicker?

Tags: angular, internationalization, bootstrap-select

I was trying to use i18n function of selectpicker in angular 7.
From:http://thetheme.io/theadmin/form/picker-select.html, it said adding data-lang="zh_CN" can change the language but it doesnt work in my code.
When I add "./node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/i18n/defaults-zh_CN.min.js" to angular.json, it successfully shows the Chinese language by default but I cant change it back to English by adding data-lang attribute. When I add both en_US and zh_CN, it only shows the latest one. What can I do to change the language dynamically?

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-lang="zh_CN" multiple 
data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" [(ngModel)]="selected" 
(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [disabled]="disabled">
  <option *ngFor="let option of data?.options" value="{{option.id}}">
    {{option.text}}
  </option>
</select>
//it doesnt work
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as you.

[This](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1653) helped me.

Try to add:

```
data-count-selected-text="Your text: ({0})"
```